# Name of the notation that goes like /<command> [arg0|arg1]

Tags: command, minecraft, notation, formal-languages, minecraft-commands

I know there is a notation or convention that for example describes the usage of a command (in a shell for example).

```
/<command> [arg0|arg1]
```

means the following is a right way of expressing/using the command: `/TheNameOfTheCommand arg0` or `/TheNameOfTheCommand arg1`.
It is a bit like RegEx or a formal language. Minecraft uses this notation too to describe the syntax of their command. And I once heard about it by a professor in a programming lecture. That's the reason I think it must be a real convention.
Do you know the name of this convention or does it exist at all?

Comment: Like the UNIX manuals, when you type let's say `man ls` in a shell ?

Comment: @kissu yes, but like a the way of properly documenting how to use such a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a convention, but not a standard. Or maybe it would be more accurate to say that it is a convention adapted from a collection of standards which differ in details, except that the standards derive from the conventional use, and it's more common to find other variants than strict application of the standards.

The use of angle brackets to delimit grammatical variables goes back to Peter Backus' notation to describe the original Algol (1959); the use of brackets to donate optionality and vertical bars to list alternatives was used in the definition of Pascal (1974) and promoted by Niklaus Wirth in a note published in 1977 (“What Can We Do About the
Unnecessary Diversity of Notation for
Syntactic Definitions”).

In the Pascal report, it was called "Extended Backus Naur Form", and it is one of a number of similar notations which go by that name. I think that's unfortunate because it doesn't acknowledge Wirth's contribution but if you called it WBNF people would probably think you were talking about a radio station.

(Wirth didn't always use angle brackets. In the published version of the Pascal report, grammatical variables were printed on italics, but in the widely-distributed typed manuscript, angle brackets were used. Similarly, literal tokens were sometimes typeset in boldface and sometimes typed surrounded by quotation marks.)